# Action bar icon not showing in Action bar in Nexus

Tags: android, android-layout

I have done quite a search, but could not resolve my error. Please help!!

I was getting those options previously and **were working fine**, but after doing some changes and few builds, I realized that they are not showing any more. I seriously dont even remember what changes I made.

**While using Samsung Duos 4.1.2 I can get the options[but NOT in action bar], they are coming from the menu button on the device itself**.

I need those options in both Nexus and Samsung device.

**For following things I have taken care of**-
- showAction="always"
- My class is extending "Activity"
- Not using Toolbar widget from v7, using the XMLs
- Theme Compatibility[**Not sure**]

Comment: share your xml and other relevant code please

Answer (score 0):

Try with. call this method inside **onCreate()** in activity

```
private void setOverflowIcon(){
        try {
            ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
            Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
            if(menuKeyField != null) {
                menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
                menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```